# PHP & MySQL secure web application - Whole web site as single index.php file yes or no?

Tags: php, mysql, session, procedure

I am working on web application that will use PHP & MySQL. Application will process confidential data. I need to make it as secure as possible.

I dont want password for MySQL user that application is using to connect to database to be written in PHP file in clear text format(root account for example).

Because of that I made pseudo MySQL Role system with stored procedures. Users will login to application with their MySQL username and password. They will have privilege only to execute MySQL stored procedures but not SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE privileges on tables that are used inside of stored procedures. Definer of stored procedures will be root account.

I have one problem with that. And that is: I dont want to store login form data ( password for examole) in session in clear text format. I cant transfer mysql connection resource object from one page to another using session.

I am thinking right now to make whole web application as one big index.php file. That way I will have MySQL connection resource allways available when I need it.

Are there batter ways to do this? Probably. I dont want to regret my choice after too much work wasted :).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One big file it's not a design at all, it's a mistake. Sessions can be  used by any scripts in domain, read the manual.

Comment: And how to you think sessions can help me? I dont want to write password filed data in session.

Comment: I don't see what having or not having everything in a single file has to do with anything. It certainly has nothing to do with storing MySQL credentials.

Comment: Listen. I dont want to use this $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'] because it will be stored in clear text format on HDD. I cant use this $connection = mysql_connect($db_host.":".$db_port, $fuser, $fpass); $_SESSION['connection'] = $connection; It is just not working. I cant transfer $connection from one page to other using session it is not working.

Comment: @BozoCvetkovski, Voting to close... you have now contradicted yourself several times, and it isn't clear what you want.  Please read the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and try again when you have narrowed your question to a specific issue that you are having, and can articulate that question clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a design pattern called [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern), basically what it does is the entire application is served through one page. You implement your own dispatcher and the dispatcher handles all the requests. Such as which object to instantiate or which page to include. This limits the security exploitation for unknown objects.

Also, for the Session hijacking you can implement your prevention mechanisms by monitoring and checking for

1. User Agent
2. Session regenerate id
3. Tokens

The database part is fairly impressive but **may add** additional complexities if someone else has to extend, debug your application. You can use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or even a better alternative an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) such as [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org) or [Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

The major security exploits are through XSS and CSRF for that you will have to implement token passing mechanism within your forms and check for " origin of request".

Lastly, i would like to point out there are various security exploits possible in an web application. To counter these exploits lots of good frameworks exist. These issues and vulnerabilities are pre-dealt there. You can consider on the bussiness logic and let someone else handle that for you. Contrary to popular belief using frameworks will actually steepen your growth over the architectures, security and requests.

Hope this help !! cheers !

Comment: What you think about using this: session.save_handler = mm . It will store session data in RAM. http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/mm/ This HTTP stateless thing is killing me. I am realy close to trash all HTML and PHP and start to learn C#.

Comment: @BozoCvetkovski, Yes, because the language you choose makes a real difference in the fundamentals of how HTTP works. `</sarcasm>`

Comment: And every C# application is using HTTP yes?. NO. Now, just skip me plz.

Answer (score 1):

You still have to save the username and password to session. but dont save password in clear text , use openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt with your own hash.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php

but this function appears from PHP 5.3.0 above

Comment: What does it matter?  The session storage should be protected on the server, and session data is never passed directly to the client.

Comment: Thats right.. the content of session never passed to client. But he asked "Users will login to application with their MySQL username and password" and dont want clear text password saved in session. perhaps you can easily *grep* session temporary files on server then get the password clearly.

Comment: Yes, and no encryption will matter one bit.  Again, if he is worried about his sysadmin doing this, the sysadmin can easily use the **same PHP script** to decode the passwords.

Comment: Ok what if I am not worried about sysadmin at all? What if someone gain access to server using some exploit that has nothing to do with application itself? I just don't like idea of storing password for application that will process financial information in clear text format anywhere on the server.

Comment: @BozoCvetkovski, I'm mortified that you are writing anything processing financial information.  I certainly hope you don't work for *my* bank.  You don't understand that **it doesn't matter**.  If someone has access to your server, anything encrypted/decrypted server-side is easily compromised, your application can be easily modified to steal credentials, HTTPS usage is meaningless, and I could go on and on.

Comment: Brad, if this application connects to MySQL with root account in background then SQL INJECTION is more possible. No user of this application will have GRANT to do SELECT * from mysql.user; This way I dont protect application only from someone that has local access to server but also from someone that connects to it remotely.

If all my data is in database why not use MySQL options to protect it?

Comment: We do agree that someone who has access to server (sysadmin) can do what ever he likes with it. I just try to make it more hard for someone to steal information from database.

Answer (score 1):

You should never need to store passwords in the session and there is no need to create individual MySQL users for each user of your application. These things don't make your application more secure and could actually make it less secure.

Here are some suggestions:

- Create one MySQL user with only the necessary permissions to read the data you need.
- Store the MySQL connection information in a PHP file that is outside the document root and include this file in your PHP files that need access to the database.
- Create a table in the database to store user accounts and always hash their password before saving it to the table. You can use this table to authenticate your users when they sign in.
- When the user signs in, simply store a flag in the session, like their user_id. This is enough to identify who they are and that they are signed in. If the value is not in the session, then they are not signed in.
- You don't need to put everything in one PHP file. It's OK to have more than one file.

You may want to try using a framework, like Symfony, CodeIgniter, or CakePHP because they will have tutorials that can help you create a secure application. Keep in mind that security goes beyond just passwords. As Kishor points out, you also need to worry about XSS, SQL injection, CSRF, etc. A framework will really help you out with these things.

Comment: Nick this exactly what I do when I code for blog or any other web app for witch I use shared hosting. But in my case I have dedicated server and I have full control of MySQL installation. I want to make batter use of it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't make your application one giant file.

Put your DB credentials in an include outside of the web root.  Then, make sure only the users that need it can open it.  That's how this is generally done.

Comment: I know how it is generally done. But that's just not acceptable for me. Database administrator and Server administrator is not always same person.

Comment: If it can be read by your PHP script, your server admin can **definitely** get at it, no matter what you try to do.

Comment: But it cant be read by my PHP script. I will connect to database like this $connection = mysql_connect($db_host.":".$db_port,$_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']); When done whole PHP script will be encrypted so no one can change code.

Comment: @BozoCvetkovski, ... Wait, so you're going to let your users enter what database host/port/username/password to use?  And, you're worried about your sysadmin making something insecure...

Comment: One more thing I will not let anyone use application if they dont use HTTPS to access it. That means server admin cant use Snifer to get password.

Comment: @BozoCvetkovski, I don't even know where to begin.  Your assumptions are so wrong and backwards that your entirely application is likely littered with glaring security issues.

Comment: Are you really going through all this trouble just so that your host can't read database contents? Dude, he has the root account. He can read your database contents and there's nothing you can do except switch to a provided you can trust.

Comment: No man this will not be hosted on shared web hosting or any other shared server. I will use dedicated server for this and it will be hosted at my company. And only I will have root account.

Comment: @BozoCvetkovski, Then, what is the problem?  You're afraid of yourself?  Now your posts make no sense at all.

Comment: There are OS level privileges and there MySQL level privileges. And no users will not need to enter host and port they will be hardcoded in app.